# python stdout=subprocess.pipe in proper format

Tags: python, subprocess

My is code using

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(proc.stdout.readline())
```

Getting result in below format.

[image]

But i want to count and get the columnnames which has the only `Datatype` `CLOB`and `BLOB` and Store them in variable want to use in further process . 
The number of  `Datattype` of `BLOB` and `Clob` is dynamic.

For example:-

```
-----------------------------------------------
| COLUMN_NAME          | DATA_TYPE            |
-----------------------------------------------
| C460                 | VARCHAR2             |
| C459                 | CLOB                 |
| C458                 | VARCHAR2             |
| C457                 | VARCHAR2             |
| C456                 | CLOB                 |
| C8                   | BLOB                 |
| C60901               | VARCHAR2             |
-----------------------------------------------
```

In this case i should get 3 variable `C459,C456,C8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I would go for regular expression

```
re.findall('(?m)C(\d+)(?=.+[CB]LOB)', proc.stdout.read())
```

where

- *(?m)* indicates multiline search,
- *C(\d+)* - C character, followed by numbers
- *(?=.+[CB]LOB)* - non-consuming unspecified character sequence, followed by BLOB or CLOB

This one-liner will give you list of all columns you are interested in.

**EDIT:**

This is a break-down - I replaced output with constant string

```
In [84]: import re

In [85]: COL_RE = re.compile('(?m)(C\d+)(?=.+[CB]LOB)')

In [86]: output = '''-----------------------------------------------
    ...: | COLUMN_NAME          | DATA_TYPE            |
    ...: -----------------------------------------------
    ...: | C460                 | VARCHAR2             |
    ...: | C459                 | CLOB                 |
    ...: | C458                 | VARCHAR2             |
    ...: | C457                 | VARCHAR2             |
    ...: | C456                 | CLOB                 |
    ...: | C8                   | BLOB                 |
    ...: | C60901               | VARCHAR2             |
    ...: -----------------------------------------------'''

In [87]: columns = COL_RE.findall(output)

In [88]: columns
Out[88]: ['C459', 'C456', 'C8']
```

Next time, you should come more prepared

Comment: giving me only ['459', '456'] this result .removing C from result not sure why

Comment: @IndrajitSwain, if yo move _C_ into brackets, you will get it too. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: I am getting the column names but i dont want to print those .i want to store in variable . Assignment will work in your case?

Comment: @IndrajitSwain, obviously, you are very new to Python (or programming for that part). I am surprised - because _subprocess_ is not exactly newby-level package. You should learn programming... Just assign operation result to a variable.

Comment: Definitely i am new to Python but expected output should be dynamically assigned to variable . And in my case i dont know how much time this BLOB or CLOB will come . If it was single variable i can go ahead and do that . My further code will not work if i will do assign multiple value to single variable .

Comment: This snippet produces _list_ - mutable equivalent of C _array_, an object that may be assigned to a variable. I could have demonstrated - if you provided textual data, and not a screenshot.

Comment: can you please help with this solution .

Comment: Is there anyway if i wanted to select Varchar2 column as well . How to compile multiple String .